# TypeError: $.doTimeout is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, timeout, synchronous

my code is the following:

```
$("p").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
})

  $.doTimeout('myLoop', 5000, function() {
      ++i;
        timeleft = calctime(id, jsondata);
        document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML = timeleft;
      /* From the docs: "If the callback returns true, the doTimeout loop will execute again, after the delay, creating a polling loop until the callback returns a non-true value." */
      return i == 50 ? false : true;
  });
};
```

the JS is implemented in my laravel server so maybe that is causing problems.

I've tried the following things:
1 download the jquery file instead of using the google service 
2 add a different jquery function (the top part of the code) to see if jquery works correctly. which it does.

My goal is to make a loop that has a synchronous delay (unlike javascripts asynchronous setTimeout) so the code runs through the loop once every 5 seconds.

Jquery is working since the top piece of my code is functioning correctly.

the Jquery i am using is version 3.3.1 on Mozilla Firefox

can anyone provide some information why doTimeout isn working?

Alright so i made this snippet but here i don think the doTimeout library is working properly since i get two errors now. hope it helps

```js
var i = 0;
$.doTimeout( 100, function(){
  i++;
  document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = i;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dotimeout/1.0/jquery.ba-dotimeout.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Download https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout and inject it into your script tag

Comment: `doTimeout` is not a core jQuery function. It has been developed as an extension. Refer here for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/hTPBP/

Comment: @nikhil this is the same as the answer below. i provided more information in a comment there since it didn't change the error. thanks anyways

Comment: @Niels - Have you been able to solve your issue?

Comment: @nikhil i have not sadly. i added the jquery + doTimeout plugin correctly but i still get the same error.

Comment: Can you create a plunker or fiddle for the same?

Comment: @nikhil i added a snippet in the post. it gets the same error along with another error saying the library link isn't working though. i know for a fact my own library is working at home.

Comment: Check here - http://jsfiddle.net/x0xob67f/5/ - It is working with some basic code.

Comment: @nikhil meh that didnt help either. anyyways i've now made some kind of workaround with calling a function from inside that function including setTimeout.   its ugly, its bad, but it works so i'm happy

Comment: @Niels - Great you have a working code. Just a thought, try an wrap your code under jQuery.ready function and see if it helps in your case.

Comment: @nikhil thanks but i already have my code wrapped in window.onload() = function(){} which basicly does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround for the problem without using doTimeout.

```
function fuckit(timeleft, id, jsondata){
  setTimeout(function(){

      timeleft = calctime(id, jsondata);
      document.getElementById("timeleft").innerHTML = timeleft;
      fuckit(timeleft, id, jsondata);
  }, 1000);
}
```

its basicly a function call within itself.

I wouldn't recommend anyone to do this because it's basicly bad coding but it works and since its only a school project i'm satisfied with it.

Comment: idk why but i can't accept this answer... fkn stackoverflow at its best

Answer (score 1):

You can [download](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout) dotimeout plugin. Because it's not a part of jQuery core.
Then inject it into your `script` tag. The error will disappear after.

Comment: after adding this in html still get the same error (yes i did download).
    <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.ba-dotimeout.min.js')}}"></script>

Comment: Call this after you call jQuery, if that not still work, make sure that that your path is correct (Check your network tab into the devtool).

Comment: the script line is after jquery and the network tab says the status is "200" and green. so that looks good however i still have the error.

Comment: checkout this documentation: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/docs/files/jquery-ba-dotimeout-js.html.

Comment: i added console.log("test") to the dotimeout file and it shows in my console. i then copied the code from the documentation but i still get the same error.